# Conditional imports golang

Tags: go

I am quite new with Go, and I am struggling to import a package only if it exists. Is there a way to do this? I tried with "_" before the package name, but if the package does not exist the program won't compile. I am aware that I could be on the wrong road, but how else should I treat this case in which I want to import a package only if it exists?

Comment: I did found  a solution to keep all those resources in the database, and not to import them.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an idiomatic Go app... Go supports plugins, that you can import at runtime, but I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: There might be a good reason for this question: imagine that you have a CLI which has a parameter which will determine if you are going to use a CGo wrapper to a system library (which may not exist for a particular architecture/operating system) and fallback to a pure Go library instead (which might be slower/limited).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible with Go. As a statically compiled language you can only compile a binary if all its dependencies exist.
Can you give us some more details on why you need this in the first place? Maybe there is a simpler or more idiomatic way to achieve your idea.

Comment: I am trying to build a "mini-cms" in which i want to include basic models like user, logging and handlers associated with them etc. When importing this "cms" in another application, i want to be able to add to those models and handlers.  So what i did try is to import in the "mini-cms" some package from the application, but only if the application exist.I already have strong doubts that this approach will work, but i am trying to figure it  how this should work

Comment: My advise to you would be - design your Go package (library) with abstractions (interfaces). So design your functions and methods to accept simple interfaces (preferably with one or two methods only) and return either interfaces or structs. This way, when an application imports your package, it will be able to use a custom implementation of the interfaces (for example for logging, tracing or metrics etc.) The library needs to be application-agnostic so for example if you construct an object which expects a `Logger` interface and the application hasn't provided one - use a NoOp logger.